# C# reactiveX multitouch drag clear buffer on OnPointerUp Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive, unirx

I'm trying to implement multitouch drag in unirx for unity. I use the `Buffer(count, skip)` overload to get last to events for each finger and calculate the distance.

I now would like the clear the Buffer when a finger is lifted, otherwise the old value that is still in the buffer will create a large delta.

```cs
 private IObservable<TwoFingerDragEventData> CalculateDelta(IObservable<PointerEventData> dragEvent, int pointerId) {

    return dragEvent
      .Where(data => data.pointerId == pointerId)
      .Select(data => data.position)
      .Buffer(2, 1)
      .Select((IList<Vector2> list) => new TwoFingerDragEventData(
        Vector2.Distance(list[0], list[1]),
        list[1] - list[0]
      ))
    ;
  }
```

Comment: You need three instructions in the method. 1) var results = dragEvent ( and the rest of your query) 2) Clear buffer 3) return results;

Comment: @jdweng The question is how do I clear that buffer? The buffer is internal to Observable and does not offer such functionality as far as I know.

Comment: Isn't it dragEvent.data?  No it is not internal to Observable.  It is passed to the Event when it is registered and is always the same object.

Comment: You're better off using `Switch()` operator for resting observables. You first build up a `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and `.Switch()` turns it into an `IObservable<T>` whereby only the latest inner values from the most recent outer observable is then produced.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes that is how I did it, see answer below.
@jdweng dragEvent is an `IObservable<PointerEventData>´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now by wrapping the whole thing into another observable.

I use a `BehaviourSubject<bool> isDragActiveSource` which is set to `true` on drag start event and set to `false` on drag stop event.

```cs
isDragActiveSource
  .AsObservable()
  .Where(isActive => isActive == true)
  .SelectMany((bool _) => {
    IObservable<TwoFingerDragEventData> firstTouch = CalculateDelta(onDrag, 0);
    IObservable<TwoFingerDragEventData> secondTouch = CalculateDelta(onDrag, 1);

    return firstTouch.Zip(
      secondTouch,
      (TwoFingerDragEventData left, TwoFingerDragEventData right) => TwoFingerDragEventData.Avg(left, right
    ).TakeUntil(isDragActive.Where(isActive => isActive == false));
  })
```

When the BehaviourSubject emits `false` `firstTouch` and `secondTouch` Observables are completed (`takeUntil`) and when it becomes `true` again they are re-created.